# How to force returning multiple lines in SQL when there are duplicates inside "in" clause (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

My need may seems kind of odd but I need to extract a full column from an excel file and paste it inside a "IN" clause. In this column there are many duplicate values.

The SQL query would look like something like this :

```
SELECT pack.pack_lib,
  upub.usr_nni,
  upub.usr_email
FROM t_package pack
LEFT OUTER JOIN t_user upub ON upub.usr_id = pack.usr_id_publication
WHERE pack.pack_lib in(
'07655_23687_30863',
'07655_23687_30863',
'07432_76544_67890'
)
ORDER BY pack.date_publication DESC;
```

As you can see in this example, there are 2 duplicate values in the "IN" clause, and the standard behaviour of this query is to return a single value for these 2 values.

**BUT I need to get two lines (which will be the same) and not a single one.**

The above is just an example, but there wll be many values, some duplicates, and other not duplicates.

How to achieve this ? I work with **ORACLE** on version **9.2.0.8.0**

Comment: Which database system are you using?

Comment: JOIN the values instead.

Comment: It's an ORACLE database

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `JOIN` instead of semi-join (the `IN` syntax). The following query should work on Oracle:

```
SELECT pack.pack_lib,
  upub.usr_nni,
  upub.usr_email
FROM t_package pack
LEFT OUTER JOIN t_user upub ON upub.usr_id = pack.usr_id_publication
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT '07655_23687_30863' pack_lib FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '07655_23687_30863' FROM dual
) t
  ON pack.pack_lib = t.pack_lib;
```

SQL Server and PostgreSQL should allow also the following syntax

```
SELECT pack.pack_lib,
  upub.usr_nni,
  upub.usr_email
FROM t_package pack
LEFT OUTER JOIN t_user upub ON upub.usr_id = pack.usr_id_publication
LEFT OUTER JOIN (VALUES ('07655_23687_30863'), ('07655_23687_30863')) AS t(pack_lib)   
  ON pack.pack_lib = t.pack_lib;
```

Comment: Just a note, a SELECT without a FROM clause isn't really a _universal_ solution. And your second query is ANSI/ISO SQL standard - using the optional features F641, Row and table constructors, F591, Derived tables and F661, Simple tables.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please check my edit on my question ? it looks like your unversal solution would be difficult to implement with a "in" clause different than the example I provided. The clause will contain many values, containing some duplicates, but not all values will be duplicates. Moreover, the query does not work because the "where" clause is missing

Comment: @RadimBača Unfortunately I have this error : ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword" and I still wonder how to implement your solution with various values and not only two duplicates

Comment: @naspy971, simply put your various values in a separate table and join.

Comment: `AS t` is invalid syntax for a table alias in Oracle, you need to remove the `AS` keyword. Also `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is incorrect if you are trying to match the functionality of a `WHERE ... IN` filter; you want an `INNER JOIN`. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=2e4416b7e11591039cc00b090427a1a2)

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, you can `INNER JOIN` to a table collection expression:

```sql
SELECT pack.pack_lib,
       upub.usr_nni,
       upub.usr_email
FROM   t_package pack
       LEFT OUTER JOIN t_user upub
         ON upub.usr_id = pack.usr_id_publication
       INNER JOIN TABLE(SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST(
         '07655_23687_30863',
         '07655_23687_30863',
         '07432_76544_67890'
       )) l
         ON pack.pack_lib = l.COLUMN_VALUE
ORDER BY pack.date_publication DESC;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t_user(usr_id, usr_nni, usr_email) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 'alice@example.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 'beryl@example.com' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE t_package(usr_id_publication, pack_lib, date_publication) AS
SELECT 1, '07655_23687_30863', DATE '2022-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '07432_76544_67890', DATE '2022-01-02' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | PACK_LIB | USR_NNI | USR_EMAIL |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 07432_76544_67890 | 2 | beryl@example.com |
> | 07655_23687_30863 | 1 | alice@example.com |
> | 07655_23687_30863 | 1 | alice@example.com |

---

If you do not have visibility of the `SYS.ODCI*LIST` types then you may be able to create a user-defined collection type:

```sql
CREATE TYPE string_list AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(20);
```

then use:

```sql
SELECT pack.pack_lib,
       upub.usr_nni,
       upub.usr_email
FROM   t_package pack
       LEFT OUTER JOIN t_user upub
         ON upub.usr_id = pack.usr_id_publication
       INNER JOIN TABLE(string_list(
         '07655_23687_30863',
         '07655_23687_30863',
         '07432_76544_67890'
       )) l
         ON pack.pack_lib = l.COLUMN_VALUE
ORDER BY pack.date_publication DESC;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=bebcef8d77c3fe682bef81f5a422dd07)*

Comment: Unfortunately I have this error : ORA-00904: "SYS"."ODCIVARCHAR2LIST": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier" Maybe it's because it's an old version of Oracle (9.2.0.8.0)

Comment: @naspy971 You can ask the DBA if they can grant access to that type or you can try to create your own collection and use that instead. Alternatively, you can use the `SELECT ... FROM DUAL UNION ALL SELECT ... FROM DUAL UNION ALL SELECT ... FROM DUAL` solution in the other answer.